# signalr - programatically scaling up (from azure function)

Tags: azure, function, signalr, scale

Trying to figure out a good way to scale up/down (ex: from Free to Standard) a SignalR Service programmatically from an Azure timer Function (C#).  The function has a managed identity with the Contributor role to the SignalR Service already.

Any thoughts on how to do this and what Nuget libraries would be best?  Examples with a managed identity would be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a resource (control plane) level change, you will need to use the [`Azure.ResourceManager.SignalR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/resourcemanager.signalr-readme?view=azure-dotnet) SDK which [supports Managed Identity](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.ResourceManager.SignalR_1.1.0/doc/dev/mgmt_quickstart.md#authenticate-the-client).

In your scenario, I assume you have the Resource ID, so you can use the SDK to fetch the latest configuration and perform updates as shown [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.ResourceManager.SignalR_1.1.0/doc/dev/mgmt_quickstart.md#managing-existing-resources-by-id).

Do note the following warning that the Azure Portal has for converting between Free and other tiers of Azure SignalR Service

[image]